# Select one value from XML Document

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq

I just want ONE value from an XML file using VB. The XML file is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Books>
    <Book ID="12345">
        <Name>One Flew Over The Cuckoo's Nest</Name>
        <ISBN>Some cataloging ID</ISBN>
        <Author>Ken Kesey</Author>
        <More>Something here</More>
    </Book>
</Books>
```

In this example, I just want to get the ISBN number of the book with the Author "Ken Kesey." I tried this;

```
        Dim xl As XElement = XElement.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\Books.xml")
        Dim Auth As String = From elem In xl.Elements("Books").Elements("Book")
                             Where elem.Element("ISBN").Value = "Some cataloging ID"
                             Select elem.Element("Author").Value
```

And many variations of the same, to no effect.

Thank you for looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to query XML and find *ISBN* of a book based on the *Author* element.

I used `.Parse()` method because I didn't want to create a file.

> VB.NET

```
Sub Main
    Dim xelem As XElement = XElement.Parse("<Books>
    <Book ID='12345'>
        <Name>One Flew Over The Cuckoo's Nest</Name>
        <ISBN>Some cataloging ID</ISBN>
        <Author>Ken Kesey</Author>
        <More>Something here</More>
    </Book>
</Books>")

    Dim ISBN As String = xelem.Elements("Book") _
        .Where(Function(x) x.Element("Author").Value.Equals("Ken Kesey")) _ 
        .[Select](Function(x) CStr(x.Element("ISBN").Value)).FirstOrDefault()

    Console.WriteLine(ISBN)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

More concise form (leverage VB.NET XML Literals):

```vb
Dim books =
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Books>
        <Book ID="12345">
            <Name>One Flew Over The Cuckoo's Nest</Name>
            <ISBN>Some cataloging ID</ISBN>
            <Author>Ken Kesey</Author>
            <More>Something here</More>
        </Book>
    </Books>
Dim isbn = books.<Books>.<Book>.Where(Function(b) b.<Author>.Value = "Ken Kesey").<ISBN>.Value
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your solution would not build. In my example xl is the XElement so my isbn= would begin with xl.<Books>.<Book> which causes an error that says 'Leading "." or "!" can only appear inside a "With" statement. and it spaces everything out in an odd way.

Comment: Why would not build? This works for me. If you'd use XDocument, then it will work.